# Combine two arrays and insert into database in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [char_id] => 205
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [char_id] => 954
        )
)
```

And this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [england] => 523
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [poland] => 9546
        )
)
```

How I can combine this arrays for inserting in database? I use codeigniter! I want this result:

```
$data =  Array
        (
            Array
                (
                    [char_id] => 205
                    [england] => 523
                )
        
            Array
                (
                    [char_id] => 954
                    [poland] => 9546
                )
        )
```

I want to use function `insert_batch` `$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);`

Number of elements from arrays is different but same count every time!

Comment: Actually it's quite simple. You need to understand how to use array tags for example var_dump($data1[0][0]); and using a foreach loop to build new array.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arrayA = array();
$arrayA[] = array("char_id"=>205);
$arrayA[] = array("char_id"=>954);

$arrayB = array();
$arrayB[] = array("england"=>523);
$arrayB[] = array("poland"=>9546);

$arrayC = array();
foreach($arrayA as $key=>$a){
    $arrayC[$key] = array_merge($arrayA[$key],$arrayB[$key]);
}

print_r($arrayC);
```

Comment: Please close duplicate questions instead of answering them. When duplicate questions are answered, the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) cannot do its important work.  When you do answer, always explain your solution.